# How to call vb script from javascript using response.write

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I try to call vb function from this javascript but I can't call that vb.
I need to call vb function inside this javascript code.. I had embeded javascript into vb code using `response.write`

Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
Response.Write("<" & "script>")
Response.Write("var r =confirm(""File Already Exist! Are you want to continue?"");")
Response.Write("if (r==true)")
Response.Write("{")
Response.Write("function callVB()")
Response.Write("{")
```

I want to call this function `messagebox2()` it was in vb function:

```
Response.Write("MessageBox2();")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("else")
Response.Write("{")
Response.Write("function callVB1()")
Response.Write("{")
Response.Write("'" & strFilename & "';")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("<" & "/script>")
```

When I click ok button it not call the function `messagebox2()`

Comment: Can someone give me suggestion of the solution

Comment: Hi user714435 - your question is not clear. Is this in a browser? In IE? What is this "Response" class/scope?

Comment: i develop website.. i test using IE.. I need to call MessageBox2 function inside that javascript. -Response.Write("MessageBox2();")-

Comment: You can't do that. You will have to use AJAX in order to have client side JavaScript trigger server side code.

Comment: can you give an example of using ajax..

Comment: @user714435: please Google for "Ajax tutorial" or "Ajax introduction"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure  what you are hoping to accomplish, but if your are trying to call a clientside vbscript from a clientside javascript then here is an example which may guide you:

```
 <%
 Response.Write ("<" & "script type=""text/VBScript"">"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("<!--"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("  sub VBFunc()"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("      Msgbox( ""Hello From VBScript"")"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("  end sub"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("//-->"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("<" & "/script>"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("<" & "script type=""text/javascript"">"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("<!--"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("  if (confirm(""File Already Exists! Do you want to continue?""))"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("  {"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("      VBFunc();"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("  }else{"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("      alert('you clicked Cancel');"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("  }"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write (" //-->"& vbcrlf)
 Response.Write ("<" & "/script>"& vbcrlf)

%>
```